# Register php to sql server Postman

Tags: php

when executing my register.php method and verifying it by POSTMAN I do not get any results, and when verifying in my preuse table of my SQL database I do not see any saved record.

**This is my code register.php**

```
  try {
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$host,1433; Database=$dbname", $user, $password);
       if( $dbh === false ) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        
    $json=file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data=json_decode($json);
    
      $stm = $dbh->query("INSERT INTO AUT_APP_PREUSO (IDPERSONAL,IDVEHICULO,IDPREGUNTAS,RESPSI,RESPNO,RESPNA,RESPIVSS,RESPDSS,RESPFM,RESPFS,OBSERVACION,FIRMA,FECHAREGISTRO,IDDISPOSITIVO,NOMBREDISPOSITIVO) 
            VALUES  ('".$data->{'idper'}."',
                     '".$data->{'idveh'}."',
                     '".$data->{'idpre'}."',
                     '".$data->{'respsi'}."',
                     '".$data->{'respno'}."',
                     '".$data->{'respna'}."',
                     '".$data->{'respivss'}."',
                     '".$data->{'respdss'}."',
                     '".$data->{'respfm'}."',
                     '".$data->{'respfs'}."',
                     '".$data->{'obs'}."',
                     '".$data->{'freg'}."',
                     '".$data->{'iddisp'}."',
                     '".$data->{'nombdis'}."')
                     ");
                     
        if( $stm === false) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }
                     
     $stmt->execute();
    $res=$stm-> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(!$res) $mensaje="ERROR";
    else $mensaje="GRABADO";
    
    sqlsrv_free_result($res);
    sqlsrv_close($dbh);  
    
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $response = array("resultado" => $mensaje);
    echo json_encode($response);
    


 } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
        exit;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using PDO, take advantage of [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: You also have some typos. You name your prepared query `$stm`, but then execute `$stmt`, which doesn't exist. You also try to use `sqlsrv_*` commands even though you're using PDO, so that won't work.

Comment: If you're right and sorry for the topographical error, about prepared statements I'm going to improve the code, thanks for the advice.